# Is their any way out to make the cylinder guage fusion chart horizontally aligned?

Tags: xml, charts, fusioncharts

I am using the cylinder gauge fusion chart shown in this example link http://www.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Gallery/Cylinder1.html , can we make this cylinder look horizontal by any means, the xml attributes are specified in the following link http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/contents/ChartSS/Cylinder_XML.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionWidgets does not support display of the Cylinder Gauge horizontally with any XML configurations, as of now.